# Parse cloud code delay each iteraton of for loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop, parse-platform, promise, parse-cloud-code

I need to run a function on a list of ParseObjects, but since my progressTournament function is asynchronous it:

A: Cancels any existing calls to progressTournament.
B: Returns status.success prematurely.

My understanding is that I need to have progressTournament return a promise, and somehow delay my code until that promise is resolved, however my understanding of promises is too limited to figure out how to implement it.

I would really appreciate some help on this, hope to hear back from someone soon.

**Background Job Code**

```
Parse.Cloud.job('progressTournaments', function(request, status)
{
    var tournamentsQuery = new Parse.Query('Tournament');
    tournamentsQuery.lessThan('nextRoundTime', moment().toDate());

    console.log('Finding tournaments that are due to progress...');
    tournamentsQuery.find(
    {
        success: function(results)
        {
            console.log('Progressing ' + results.length + 'tournaments')

            for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++)
            {
                progressTournament(results[i], null);
                // Wait here until progressTournament finishes!
            }

            status.success();
        },
        error: function(error)
        {
            status.error();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to achieve what I wanted using [Parse.Promise.when()](https://parseplatform.github.io/Parse-SDK-JS/api/classes/Parse.Promise.html#methods_when)

```
tournamentsQuery.find(
function(tournaments)
{
    var promises = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < tournaments.length; i++)
        promises.push(tournamentUtils.progressTournament(tournaments[i]));

    return Parse.Promise.when(promises);
}).then(
function(progressedTournaments)
{
    response.success("All tournaments progressed");
},
function(error)
{
    response.error(error);
});
```

If they needed to be done in series rather than in parallel, could use [Parse.Query.each()](https://parseplatform.github.io/Parse-SDK-JS/api/classes/Parse.Query.html#methods_each) instead

Should note that now using response instead of status since migrated to self hosted parse server since this question was posted.